# Grep inside while loop in bash

Tags: bash, grep

Can any one help me how to grep on an output inside while loop in bash shell

```
root@localhost:~# while true; do 'netstat -tuplen | grep sshd'; sleep 2; done
-sh: netstat -tuplen | grep sshd: command not found
```

Comment: Remove both single quotes.

Comment: `while sleep 2; do netstat -tuplen | grep '[s]shd'; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Cyrus said, all you need to do is remove the single-quotes:

```
while true; do netstat -tuplen | grep sshd; sleep 2; done
```

or

```
while true; do
    netstat -tuplen | grep sshd
    sleep 2
done
```